# Remove one of duplicate records

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is my DB table table name is `food_user`. I use mariadb version 10.1.38.

[image]

I run the following sql query :

```
INSERT INTO food_user (NAME,re_date,re_day)
SELECT 'Alex','2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY,DAYNAME('2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY)
FROM seq_0_to_364;
```

two times. So there are two data of the same date as seen on the screenshot below.

[image]

I'd like to remove one of the two same dates.

I try this query.

```
DELETE n1 from food_user n1, food_user n2 
where n1.id > n2.id
  and n1.sum=0 and n2.sum=0
  and n1.name='Alex'
  and n2.name='Alex'
  and n1.re_date=?
  and n2.re_date=?;
```

I don't know the proper query.

Comment: What happens when you run this query...

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: OK. I edit code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how your delete query should look like.

```
delete from food_user where id in 
(
   select x.id from (select min(id) as id from food_user t group by name, re_date having count(1) = 2) as x
)
```

Comment: This code syntax error. I want to know re_date = ? this ?.

Comment: i updated, i found out you just want to delete those duplicates.

Comment: This code 1093 error. Table 'food_user' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data.

Comment: try now, i wrapped the subquery

Comment: Sorry.. this code 1054 SQL error Unknown column x.id in 'field list' Thank you so much your help